# Iterating through object properties and setting nullable properties through user input

Tags: c#

I am trying to iterate through an object's properties and prompt the user to input their value in each iteration. Some of my properties are nullable and with my current code I'm getting an error, specifically where I try to convert the user's input to a property type which is a nullable.

Is there something I can use to make the user input convert to nullable datatype please?

Here is my code:

```
someClass newObject = new someClass();

foreach(PropertyInfo prop in newObject.GetType().GetProperties()) {
  do {
    try {
      Console.WriteLine($"Enter {prop.Name} for new Object:");

      string input = Console.ReadLine();
      var convertedInput = Convert.ChangeType(input, prop.PropertyType);

      prop.SetValue(newObject, convertedInput);

      valid = true;
    } catch {
      Console.WriteLine($"INVALID INPUT - PLEASE INPUT A VALID {prop.Name} WHICH IS OF TYPE: {prop.PropertyType}");
      valid = false;
    }
  } while (!valid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype) to get the underlying type of a nullable type. If it's not a nullable type, it returns `null`, so you can check for `null` and use the actual property type instead. Like this:

```
var convertedInput = Convert.ChangeType(input,
              Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
```

Comment: This worked however, when I enter empty inputs now I am getting an error there since it's still not nullable. 
But I guess I can check whether the user's input is NullOrEmpty and just set it to null. Is that a good approach?

Comment: I think you mean that the type cannot have a null value (like `DateTime`) but the input is null? What does the actual exception say?

Comment: No I mean that since you're still converting to the underlying type, if the user inputs "" it will not be accepted. But I have figured it out so it's okay. 

Thanks again for your help though :)